# step to develop extjs pivot grid in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, extjs6

I have to develop Extjs's pivot grid in my asp.net web form. where can i  download libraries(.js files) that support for pivot grid. and how to add it in asp.net web form(aspx). im new to Extjs. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ExtJs 4, You can download it form here: https://cdn.sencha.com/pivot-grid/3.6.0/mzPivotGrid-all.js

However, I think its only legal to use it if you have Premium ExtJs license:
https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/newpkg/

It used to be standalone product that you can buy, but now it is part of ExtJs license.